# Nginx log location

Tags: nginx

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to log the exactly location uri.

If the following url was accessed

```
location / {
}
```

The nginx log would have "/" as part of the log.

If the following location was accessed

```
location /myLocation {
}
```

The nginx log would have "/myLocation" as part of the log.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could specify exact filename you want to use to avoid this strange behaviour.

```
server {
    listen 80 ;
    server_name     mysite.com ;
    location / {
        root /var/www/webapp;
    }
    location /mylocation {
        root /var/www/webapp/notmylocation;
    }
    access_log  /var/log/mysite.com-access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/mysite.com-error.log warn;
}
```